# Sorting Strings with separators in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas series with strings with separators in them, like say:

```
['160.20.2257.92', '829.328.17.39']
```

I want to sort them. If I use Seres.sort_values() like in the below code:

```
a = pd.Series(['6.0.0.0', '10.0.4.0'])
a.sort_values()
```

I get the output as :

```
1    10.0.4.0
0     6.0.0.0
```

which is quite expected since the sorting function compares 6 with 1 not 6 with 10 and since 1 is smaller it is displayed first in sorted order. What I want is it to be sorted by the first part before the separator('.'), followed by the 2nd part, and so on(i.e compare 10 & 6, followed by 0 & 0, followed by 4 & 0, finally 0 & 0)

What is the best way in Pandas, in terms of speed to achieve this, since I am dealing with a large dataset?

Comment: who wins in this case: `10.7.8.1` & `6.1.0.0` and why ?

Comment: 10 because 10 is greater than 6, we first check for 10 & 6 since there is no tie, we don't want to go further

Comment: and what is there was a tie ?

Comment: Then I would compare 7 and 1,.

Comment: I am looking for a solution in pandas, numpy since that would be fast

Comment: I don't understand, how about: `10.7.0.6` & `6.10.0.6`

Comment: if i use split('.') I will get something like a =[10, 7, 0, 6]  & b = [6, 10, 0, 6] now compare the consecutive elements. a[0], with b[0], if a[0] == b[0], I compare a[1] with b[1] and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an extension of @Ananay Mital's answer - if you wish to save an index.

```
def sort_data(series): 
    sorted_data = sorted(
                      zip(series.index, map(lambda x: tuple(map(int, x.split('.'))), series)), 
                      key=lambda x: x[1])  
    return pd.Series(
               map(lambda x: '.'.join(map(str, x[1])), sorted_data),
               index=[i[0] for i in sorted_data])

sorted_data = sort_data(series)
```

Example:

```
series
Out:
0       2.49.30.91
1      2.16.99.113
2     62.38.107.41
3     127.21.16.56
4     14.97.112.42
5      49.25.90.11
6      92.87.23.61
7    87.121.78.112
8      17.73.95.37
9     28.117.48.89
dtype: object
```

Sorted series:

```
sort_data(series)
Out:
1      2.16.99.113
0       2.49.30.91
4     14.97.112.42
8      17.73.95.37
9     28.117.48.89
5      49.25.90.11
2     62.38.107.41
7    87.121.78.112
6      92.87.23.61
3     127.21.16.56
dtype: object
```

There's no simple approach to do what you looking for with a standard `pandas` methods; also, some my attemtpts to do that with pandas was not so fast as @Ananay Mital's solution.

This approach is fast enough (approx. time to sort 100.000 ip's ~4 ms, 1.000.000 ip's ~84 ms).

If you want it work faster because dataset is huge and `O(n)/O(n*log(n))` difference matters, you can implement [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) or [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) (only if the data consists of ip's or so - domain should be restricted). Even implemented in `python`, such algorithm will be faster than built-in `sorted` because of `O(n)` complexity.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you are looking for

```
a = ['160.20.2257.92', '829.328.17.39']
b = sorted(map(lambda x: tuple(map(int, x.split('.'))), a))
final = map(lambda x: '.'.join(map(str, x)), b)
final

['160.20.2257.92', '829.328.17.39']
```

I hope this covers all corner cases